# what's the difference between those two regarding bit operations?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

say, a is an unsigned 32 bit integer.

```
a << 24
(a & 0xff)<<24
```

Similiar one, any difference for this two

```
a >> 16
(a >> 16) & 0xff
```

Comment: The second shifts only the LSB of `a`. They are completely different!

Comment: The second one will yield different results for `a > 0x00FFFFFF`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example:

```
a << 24
(a & 0xff)<<24
```

In the case of a 32-bit unsigned integer, there is no difference in the result.
From the C standard (6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators):

> The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated
>   bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of
>   the result is E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup>, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value
>   representable in the result type.
>   (...)

Your second example

```
a >> 16
(a >> 16) & 0xff
```

The seconds line truncates the result to the range 0 .. 255, while the first does not.
If you meant the difference between

```
a >> 16
(a >> 16) & 0xffff
```

then there is again no difference for unsigned 32-bit integers:

> The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. If E1 has
>   an unsigned type or if E1 has a signed type and a nonnegative value,
>   the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of E1 /
>   2<sup>E2</sup>.
>   (...)

Note that "unsigned" is important here. For signed integers, the behaviour can
be different, implementation-defined, or undefined.

Comment: What if `unsigned int` on this system is larger than 32 bits?

Comment: Then the result of `a << 24` is truncated to the size of `unsigned int`, and assigning the result to an `uint32_t` truncates it to the size of `uint32_t`. If I see it correctly, the result is the same.

Comment: I think you're correct provided that the final result is indeed truncated down to a `uint32_t` for some reason.  I didn't see that specified in the question, so I figured it was worth pointing out that caveat.

Answer (score 0):

Any difference for these two:

```
a >> 16
(a >> 16) & 0xff
```

Yes, you'll get different results for every `a > 0x00FFFFFF`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a << 24
(a & 0xff)<<24
```

no difference between results, but the  latter may avoid influencing overflow flag of register ?